# Shift a sinewave by 90 degrees in STM32

Tags: stm32, shift, phase

I am working on a STM32F446RE project. I sense a sinewave of 50 Hz in ADC (alpha) and I want to create an identical sinewave as the first one but shifted by 90 degrees (beta).

I tried to implement it with two methods. The one that works better is with Hilbert:

```
#define M 63 // filter order
float hilbert_coeffs[M+1];

void init_hilbert_coeffs() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++) {
    if (i == M/2) {
      hilbert_coeffs[i] = 0.0;
    } else {
      float n = i - M/2;
      hilbert_coeffs[i] = 1.0/(M_PI*n);
    }
  }
}

float hilbert_filter(float x) {
  static float x_buffer[M+1];
  static int x_buffer_index = 0;
  float y = 0.0;
  x_buffer[x_buffer_index] = x;
  for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++) {
    y += hilbert_coeffs[i]*x_buffer[(x_buffer_index+i)%(M+1)];
  }
  x_buffer_index = (x_buffer_index + 1) % (M+1);
  return y;
}
```

The problem is that the higher the order of the filter, the worse the signal becomes. For a 90 degree shift the order should be 63, but the signal gets chunky and the magnitude gets a bit bigger. For example:
I want this:
[sine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGMTK.png)

And with Hilbert I get this:
[hilebrt_sine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZocJo.png)

If I use lower order filter then I don't have 90 degrees phase shift. I the other method that I tried was with storing the first sinewave and use mod: `beta = alpha_LUT[(i + (NS/4)) % NS];` where NS are the elements of the array. But I want to avoid storing the alpha signal because I sense it in real time and use alpha and beta for another process (alpha-beta to dq0).
Do you know any alternatives to how I can achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Your calculation of n in the first function suffers from rounding error.  Try divide by 2.0 not 2.

Comment: It is conventional in C and C++ to use < in loops over arrays not <=.  This would mean you define M as 64 not 63 and then you don't have to keep adding 1 everywhere.  Working in a conventional way is (of course) not necessary for the code to work, but it is necessary for anyone else to be able to read it easily.

Comment: Here's another idea: To shift a fixed 50Hz frequency by 90 degrees phase is just a delay of 5ms.  You could just allocate a ring buffer to hold [5ms times your sample rate] samples, and each time you input a new sample then output the one from 5ms ago.

Comment: @TomV can you give me, please, more details about the ring buffer implementation because I don't have much experience?

About Hilbert Filter I tried to decrease the order of the filter in order to have a better signal and multiply the output with a number in order to increase the magnitude.